# Which concentration inequalities apply when moments are infinite?

Tags: probability, moments, probability-inequalities, inequality

I have 2 questions:

1. Suppose I have a finite mean but an infinite variance for a discrete distribution w/support $\{1,2,\dots\}$. Is there any probability inequality tighter than Markov in this case? The motivating example is a Yule-Simon with parameter $\lambda \in (1,2)$.
2. Suppose now the mean is infinite but a fractional moment may exist, $\mathbb{E}(X^\alpha) <\infty$, for $0<\alpha<1$. The distribution is still discrete with same support as question 1 above. In this case Markov will not apply but something else might. What would one typically use for an ineuqality in this scenario?

Comment: You switch between "mean ... is infinite" and "mean is finite but variance is infinite...", you should probably clarify and pick one of those two, as, for example, Markov applies in the latter case to nonnegative random variates but not in the former case.

Comment: @jbowman has a good point - if the variance is infinite and expectation is finite you have some results to draw from, but if the random variable is not integrable you are not able to even state many concentration results, which tend to be phrased in terms of bounds on $P \left( | X - \mathbb{E}(X)| > t \right)$.

Comment: @jbowman, good point. I was hoping for some general inequalities that hold with infinite variances, the Markov obviously still applies here but not Chebyshev. I'd rather learn something from any answer to the post so I'll phrase as mean finite, variance infinite, and not any of the 3: Chebyshev, Chernoff, or Markov.

Comment: @LucasRoberts I don't follow your response to jbowman. If you're choosing mean finite, Markov would apply, would it not?

Comment: @Glen_b, yes the Markov inequality provides a bound if the first moment is finite that is why I rephrased the question to read "*not* Markov,..." is it still not clear? or maybe is your question, why wouldn't you use Markov in this case?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. There are several issues leading to my confusion. In the comment I responded to, you have "Markov still applies" ... but then say "not ... Markov" ... note that your comment says this is for the case "mean finite" but your question body still says "mean infinite" as the reason you ruled Markov out in the question. I really don't follow what's going on now. Can you explain the comment and perhaps edit your question to clarify the circumstances (are we dealing with mean finite or not?), and if you are ruling out Markov with finite variance, indicate why you would do so.

Comment: @Glen_b, the question says "moments infinite" not necessarily the mean but I can see how that isn't very clear to a reader. Basically, I'm looking for a bound tighter than Markov in the finite mean, infinite variance case. Also, an applicable inequality for the infinite mean case, but their might be a fractional moment between 0, 1 that exists so it's really 2 questions. Apologies for the confusion, I'll clean up the question.

Comment: "I'm looking for a bound tighter than Markov in the finite mean, infinite variance case" ... is very clear, thankyou.

Comment: Markov is tight in the finite variance case ($x=a$ with probability $p$, $0$ with probability $1-p$).  It seems likely to me that you can construct distributions that get you arbitrarily close to the Markov bound in the infinite variance case (the finite variance example is the only distribution that achieves the Markov bound.)

Comment: You can check "Self-normalized process" which gives you an exponential concentration inequality even when there is no mean. (e.g., Cauchy distribution)